# What is canonicalization in xml signature?

Tags: xml, xml-signature

What is the canonicalization tag which is used in xml signatures. It is present in the `<signed info>` element. I have gone through various documents over the net. But all of them are too abstract for me to understand. It would be helpful if some one could explain what should be contained in the canonicalization tag and how should it be used?
I also have a doubt in the `<signature value>` element. What does it contain the signature of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A signature in general is used (beside **tracebility** reasons) as a prove for the recipient, that the message was not altered during its way (by a man in the middle for instance).

->**Keyword: Integrity**:

**Problem:**

XML offers several valid ways to structure same (input-)data like:

1. `<a>1</a><!--comment--> <b></b>`
2. `<a>1</a><b/>`

This makes a creation of a determinable signature hash impossible, which is a must for a working signature-verification.
For example a MD5 hash over both XML-examples above would result in complete different result-hashes, although both examples provide the same valid data in XML-form (they are semantically identical).

**Solution:**
This is, where a XML canonicalization  (c14n) comes in:
The message is formatted (canonicalized) by the sending party (client) and also after reception on receiver side (server), so that the hash does not change for same data (on XML-level).

I guess you're just curious about this stuff, cause typically you should not take care about this, as the libs (XMLDSig-libs, WS-Security-libs, ..) are taking care of this behind the scenes.

**Re 2nd question:**
The SignatureValue element contains the Base64 encoded signature result of the SignedInfo element.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Actually the signature value element contains the signature of the <signature info> element. Please change the part "Re 2nd Question" accordingly. I will accept your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for the hint regarding the 2nd question, I've edited this part.

Comment: @AydinK Great answer, however the part I'm uneasy with is: _italic_"It formats the message after its sending and before the reception on receiver-side, so that the hash does not change for same data (on XML-level)."_italic_ . My understanding is that your XML message doesn't change on the wire or anywhere in the transmission from sender to receiver. The c14n process is done on the sender side as a preamble to computing the hash (so the hash is computed on a canonical version of your message. On the receiver side, the process that validates the signature will do the same to get the same hash.

Comment: @PatriceM.: Yes, you're absolutely right. The c14n-process is not done "somewhere" between the sender-receiver, but by themselves. I've just corrected this part.

Comment: @AydinK : I have one more question - there is a canonicalization element included inside the signed info element. Then why is a "c14n" canonicalization method added in the transform also?

Comment: @PatriceM.  there is a canonicalization element included inside the signed info element. Then why is a "c14n" canonicalization method added in the transform also?